# How to assign public IP to VM in VM-scaleset in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have created a Virtual machine scale set with 2 running instances. How to assign a public IP to both the instances to manage independently?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a public IP per VM, you can do it following the tutorial below:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#public-ipv4-per-virtual-machine

But probably it is a better idea to assign a Public IP to the load balancer and then create Inbound NAT rules for each of the VMs.

See "Access Via Public Load Balancer" below:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2017/02/01/external-rdp-access-to-azure-rm-vm/